# Angular-cli 1.0 rc 0 - router-outlet in not known

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am using a single module and I did everything needed to register the routes in app.module.ts file. But the below error keep coming..not sure what is going on. Can someone please help by looking at the below detail error message.  `"Template parse errors:↵'router-outlet' is not a known element:↵1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.↵2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("<app-nav></app-nav>↵  [ERROR ->]<router-outlet></router-outlet>"): AppComponent@1:2"
originalStack
:
"Error: Template parse errors:↵'router-outlet' is not a known element:↵1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.↵2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("<app-nav></app-nav>↵  [ERROR ->]<router-outlet></router-outlet>"): AppComponent@1:2↵    at SyntaxError.ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3236:33)↵    at SyntaxError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:64595:16)↵    at new SyntaxError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:5714:16)↵    at TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:17621:19)↵    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:47610:68)↵    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:47493:62↵    at Set.forEach (native)↵    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:47493:19)↵    at createResult (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:47375:19)↵    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.567.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:2608:26)↵    at Zone.webpackJsonp.567.Zone.run (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:2404:43)↵    at http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:2957:57↵    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.567.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:2641:31)↵    at Zone.webpackJsonp.567.Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:2444:47)↵    at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:2807:35)"`

My App.component.ts file looks like :

```
 `import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  template: `<app-nav></app-nav>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
}
```

my app.module.ts file looks like,
`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavComponent } from './nav/nav.component';
import { BlogComponent } from './blog/blog.component';
import { PostblogComponent } from './blog/postblog/postblog.component';
import { BlogdetailComponent } from './blog/blogdetail/blogdetail.component';

import {BlogService} from './blog/shared/blog.service';

import {AppRoutes} from './app.route';
@NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavComponent,
        BlogComponent,
        PostblogComponent,
        BlogdetailComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes)
      ],
      providers: [BlogService],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Following is my routing module ,

```
import {Routes}  from '@angular/router';
import {BlogComponent} from './blog/blog.component';
import {BlogdetailComponent} from './blog/blogdetail/blogdetail.component';

export const AppRoutes:Routes = [
    {path:'blog',component:BlogComponent},
    {path:'blog/:id',component:BlogdetailComponent},
     {path:'', redirectTo:'/blog',pathMatch:'full'}
]
```

`

Comment: You haven't imported the router module in your NgModule. Read the routing documentation: `imports: [..., RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES)]`.

Comment: I did import RouterModule. I have updated my question by adding my app.module.ts and app.component.ts file.  It is still giving the same issue.

Comment: @user2225263 can you show us your routing module as well? :)

Comment: I have added my RoutingModule as well.

Comment: @user2225263 Your app.component has no selector, is that a typo?

Comment: Yes, it is typo as I was just massing around to find the solution.  I do have selector namely ***<app-root>*** ....I checked all I could but seems it is a caching issue OR some weird issue.  Still looking into it. will restart my machine if could not get it working :)